# Comparing a text file to another text file in python?

Tags: python

I need the ability to compare two text files. File 1 being a chat log and file 2 being a wordlist with key words in. I am struggling to get the output I desire which is ideally showing every time one of the key words in File 2 appears in the chat log which is file 1. Any ideas on how I could achieve this output?

edit*

this is the code I'm currently trying to use, however the output i get is that it prints both files to the text box within the gui. The output need is to show what lines the words from file 2 occur within the file 1. Some of the code is taken from a keyword search feature I already have working.

```
def wordlistsearch():

filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(filetypes=(("Text files", "*.txt") ,)) //file1
mtxt = filename.readline()
i =0
filename2 = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(filetypes=(("Text files", "*.txt") ,)) //file2

while i<10000:
    keystring = filename2.readline()
    print keystring
    participant = mtxt.split("(")[0]
    temppart2 = mtxt.split("(")[-1]
    keyword = temppart2.split(")")[0]
    if mtxt.find(str(keystring)) != -1:
        print i, ": ", mtxt
    i=i+1
    mtxt = filename.readline()
```

Comment: What have you tried? Include an example of your code, and detail as to why it isn't working

Comment: Can you be more specific, like posting an example of both files and what have you done/tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all the words in File 1 that are also in File2, you can use:

```
keywords = set([word for line in open("keyword_file","r") for word in line.split()])

words = set([word for line in open("log_file","r") for word in line.split()])

common = words.intersection(keywords)
```

To find the occurrence of a match while reading File 1 instead:

```
keywords = set([word for line in open("keyword_file","r") for word in line.split()])

for line in open("log_file","r"):
    for word in line:
        if word in keywords:
            print "found {0} in line {1}".format(word, line)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a very good question. Personally I think you can do this:

```
# I suppose the keywords has non repeated words separated by a space 
keywords_file = open('path_to_file_keywords')
keywords_dict = {word: 0 for word in keywords_file.readlines().strip().split(' ')} # Iterate through all the words removing '\n'characters and generate a dict

# Then read the chat log
chat_log_file = open('path_to_file_chat_log')
chat_log_words_generator = (word for word in chat_log_file.readlines().strip().split(' ')) # Create a generator with the words from the chat log


for word in chat_log_words_generator:
    try:
        word_count = keywords_dict[word]
    except KeyError:
        continue # The word is not a keyword
    word_count += 1 # increment the total
    keywords_dict[word] = word_count # override the value of the count in the dict
```

In the end the `keywords_dict` should have the count of the occurrences of all the keywords.

Comment: instead of an increment in the total occurrences of the keywords is there anyway to change it to show what line the keywords occur within the chat log? as i already have a keyword search feature that prints every line where the certain word occurs. Cheers

Comment: Great question! If you use `enumerate` on the `readlines` you'll get a tuple like `(index, item)`: `(index, line.strip() for index, line in enumerate(chat_log_file.readlines()))`. With this generator you could get the words like we did previously.

Comment: as I'm using tkinter could the open('path_to_file_chat_log') line be changed to something like tkFileDialog.askopenfile(filetypes=(("Text files", "*.txt") ,)) as i want the user to be able to select what files to compare after a button has been clicked.

Comment: I'm sorry but I never used tkinter before.